# How to Merge items within a List<> collection C#

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, collections, foreach

I have a implememtation where i need to loop through a collection of documents and based on certain condition merge the documents .

The merge condition is very simple, if present document's doctype is same as later document's doctype, then copy all the pages from the later doctype and append it to the pages of present document's and remove the later document from the collection.
Note : Both `response.documents` and `response.documents[].pages` are List<> collections.

I was trying this but was getting following exception Once I remove the document.

> collection was modified enumeration may not execute

Here is the code:

```
int docindex = 0;
foreach( var document in response.documents)
{
    string presentDoctype = string.Empty;
    string laterDoctype = string.Empty;

    presentDoctype = response.documents[docindex].doctype;
    laterDoctype = response.documents[docindex + 1].doctype;

    if (laterDoctype == presentDoctype)
    {
        response.documents[docindex].pages.AddRange(response.documents[docindex + 1].pages);
        response.documents.RemoveAt(docindex + 1);
    }
    docindex = docindex + 1;
}
```

Ex:

```
reponse.documents[0].doctype = "BankStatement"   //page count = 1
reponse.documents[1].doctype = "BankStatement"   //page count = 2
reponse.documents[2].doctype = "BankStatement"   //page count = 2
reponse.documents[3].doctype = "BankStatement"   //page count = 1
reponse.documents[4].doctype = "BankStatement"   //page count = 4
```

Expected result:

```
response.documents[0].doctype = "BankStatement"  //page count = 10
```

Please suggest.Appreciate your help.

Comment: You get the enumeration error because you alter the collection thus the enumerator gets invalidated. Use a simple for loop instead of foreach.

Comment: I'm suggesting to search for error message first - i.e. https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+collection+was+modified+enumeration+may+not+execute, which should give you good explanation of the problem for many basic .Net exceptions. That would also let you improve your question with explanation why standard approaches did not work for you (i.e. using `for` with careful indexing instead of `foreach`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to look at LINQ `GroupBy` and `Distinct` to process your `response.documents`

Example (as I cannot use your class, I give example using my own defined class):

Suppose you have `DummyClass`

```
public class DummyClass {
    public int DummyInt;
    public string DummyString;
    public double DummyDouble;
    public DummyClass() {

    }
    public DummyClass(int dummyInt, string dummyString, double dummyDouble) {
        DummyInt = dummyInt;
        DummyString = dummyString;
        DummyDouble = dummyDouble;
    }
}
```

Then doing `GroupBy` as shown,

```
DummyClass dc1 = new DummyClass(1, "This dummy", 2.0);
DummyClass dc2 = new DummyClass(2, "That dummy", 2.0);
DummyClass dc3 = new DummyClass(1, "These dummies", 2.0);
DummyClass dc4 = new DummyClass(2, "Those dummies", 2.0);
DummyClass dc5 = new DummyClass(3, "The dummies", 2.0);
List<DummyClass> dummyList = new List<DummyClass>() { dc1, dc2, dc3, dc4, dc5 };
var groupedDummy = dummyList.GroupBy(x => x.DummyInt).ToList();
```

Will create three groups, marked by `DummyInt`

Then to process the group you could do

```
for (int i = 0; i < groupedDummy.Count; ++i){
    foreach (DummyClass dummy in groupedDummy[i]) { //this will process the (i-1)-th group
        //do something on this group
        //groupedDummy[0] will consists of "this" and "these", [1] "that" and "those", while [2] "the"
        //Try it out!
    }
}
```

In your case, you should create group based on `doctype`.

Once you create groups based on your `doctype`, everything else would be pretty "natural" for you to continue.

Another LINQ method which you might be interested in would be `Distinct`. But I think for this case, `GroupBy` would be the primary method you would like to use.

Comment: Can you provide some example illustrating how to do it.

Comment: @Fabjan example added

Answer (score 0):

Use only "for loop" instead of "foreach".

foreach will hold the collection and cannot be modified while looping thru it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `groupBy`, hope this help.

```
 //mock a collection
        ICollection<string> collection1 = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            collection1.Add("BankStatement");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            collection1.Add("BankStatement2");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            collection1.Add("BankStatement3");
        }

        //merge and get count
        var result = collection1.GroupBy(c => c).Select(c => new { name = c.First(), count = c.Count().ToString() }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.name + ": " + item.count);
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

Just use **AddRange()**

```
response.documents[0].pages.AddRange(response.documents[1].pages);
```

it will merge all pages of document[1] with the document[0] into document[0]